# execute-kbd-macro apparently not working according to its doc?

Tags: functions, keyboard-macros

The doc of `execute-kbd-macro` says:

> `(execute-kbd-macro MACRO &optional COUNT LOOPFUNC)`
>   ...
>   If MACRO is a symbol, its function definition is used.

I tried <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(execute-kbd-macro 'ignore)`.
That bailed out with the following error message:

> Keyboard macros must be strings or vectors

That happens with
`emacs-version` `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-04-12`.

Is that an Emacs bug, a documentation bug, or do I misunderstand something?

Might it be that the function definition of the symbol **must** be a keyboard macro?
At least the following code works:

```el
(fset 'a (kbd "myfun"))
(execute-kbd-macro 'a)
```

**Background:** I wanted to use `apply-macro-to-region-lines` on a command in [an answer about applying `comment-indent` on a region.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51698/2370)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I think they wanted `Findirect_function` rather than `indirect_function` in that code.